# MVC Validation : wrong message displayed

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi this is the RegularExpression in my model code

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(127)]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Enter only alphabets for First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } //First Name should only use Alphabets
```

This is the validation in /home/index.aspx page

```
<%  using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "AudienceRequest" }))
    { %>
        <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true, "To request tickets, please complete the required (*) fields below and click Submit") %>


        <div>
            <label>First Name
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FirstName, "*") %></label>
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName) %>
```

Right now, the validation part works. If I enter BOB333, it won't submit the form. but the message displayed is wrong. It is still displaying "To request tickets, please complete the required (*) fields below and click Submit", instead of "Enter only alphabets for First Name"

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change

```
<%= Html.ValidationSummary(true, "To request tickets, please complete the required (*) fields below and click Submit") %>
```

to

```
<%= Html.ValidationSummary(false, "To request tickets, please complete the required (*) fields below and click Submit") %>
```

The boolean flag is to "exclude property errors" - see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee839474%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Comment: by setting it to false, it still displays the msg at the model level, but it also displays all other error msg

Comment: Yes - that is how it is supposed to work.  The thinking is that if you set it to true, you just want the model level errors at the top, and will have the property level errors throughout your page beside the appropriate control, and therefore don't need them all repeated at the top.